# Absolute Div Width not full when page scrolled inward

Tags: css, xhtml

There's a small issue with DIVs when the window width becomes smaller than the content width.

Basically; this is really hard to explain but, the page you're currently on (the stackoverflow web page) just take your window and reduce the window's width until the bottom scroll bar shows; then scroll to the bottom of the page.  You should then see the footer-wrapper showing half-way with half the content in and half the content out of the background image.

So, on one of my personal websites, I've got a footer set up exactly like stackoverflow's, is there a way around this? Or would this need to be a width updated via javascript?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters, there's no absolute positioning in Stack Overflow's footer, so I assume there's none in yours either.

SO's footer has no positioning, which means it just sits at 100% width of its parent, which is the `body` element, which also has no positioning so just sits at 100% of the window width. However, the container element on SO has a width of 960px, which may or may not be larger than your 100% body and window. When it's larger, it extends *outside* the body element, creating the gap you see at the bottom right of the page when you need to scroll. It doesn't force the body to be larger, it just extends outside.

A quick solution is to make your body min-width match your largest content width, so this issue won't occur.

Comment: Perfectos! Setting the body min-width to the largest content width and setting the div as relative did the job; Thanks Karpie!